# /platform:anycpu32bitpreferred is not a valid setting for option /target:library or /target:module

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013

I created a Windows service project and later decided to change it's output type to class library so I could include the service class in another project which would create the .exe to be installed as a service. But now when I try to build the first project it fails with the error:

> /platform:anycpu32bitpreferred is not a valid setting for option
>   /target:library or /target:module

How can I fix this?

Comment: [This is an older blog post](http://slodge.blogspot.com/2012/10/error-13-platformanycpu32bitpreferred.html), but it suggests editing the .csproj file directly and removing `<Prefer32bit>true</Prefer32bit>`, and then unloading and reloading the project in the solution.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try to

unload project (right click in solution explorer)

edit `<projectName>.csproj` (right click in solution explorer)

remove `<Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>`

reload project.